# Pass multiple variables from one module to another

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have several modules in the folder "Programm/modules" which are called by another script in "Programm".

One for example looks like this:

"calculate.py"

```
def calculate():
  x = 1 + 2
  y = 3 + 4
  return x
  return y
```

this I would like to load into another module "print.py"

```
import os
import sys
sys.path.append(".")
import modules.calculate

def print():
  print(x)
  print(y)
```

But I get the error `"ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'calculate'"`

What's wrong?

**EDIT**

Thx guys, I can now load the module with:

```
from modules.calculate import calculate
```

And I changed the return to:

```
return x, y
```

But now I get:

```
"NameError: name "x" is not defined"
```

How can I import "x" and "y" into "print.py"?

Comment: Did you create the ``__init__.py`` file in ``modules``?

Comment: not really relevant, but your mockup calculate function only returns x, as it never reaches the `return y`statement.

Comment: Considering the import error, use: ```from modules import calculate``` and use the function with ```calculate.calculate()``` or import the function with ```from modules.calculate import calculate```.

Away from import error, you will not get y-value, since your function "is done" after the first return statement. consider returning a tuple instead: ```return x, y``` and unpack it: ```x, y = calculate()```.

Comment: @TorbenKlein No, for what do I need the __init__.py?

Comment: The presence of ``__init__.py`` indicates to Python that the directory should be considered as Python Package. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/448271/what-is-init-py-for

Comment: Thx! I inserted the file, but there is no difference between `from modules import calculate`. @Ifreist: Where do I need to unpack it?

Comment: @TorbenKlein: From python 3.3 packages don't need the `__init__.py` file.

Comment: Seems you're right. I'm a dinosaur.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if your programm folder looks like this:

```
├── programm.py
├── modules
│   ├── calculate.py
```

`from modules.calculate import calculate`

EDIT:

use the value you `return` to assign it to a variable. like `x, y = calculate()`. Now you can use (these) x and y in your `print.py` like this:

```
import os
import sys
sys.path.append(".")
import modules.calculate

def print():
    x, y = calculate()
    print(x)
    print(y)
```

Comment: That worked, thanks! And how can I import "x" and "y" into the module "plot"? Because I get now the new error "NameError: "x" is not defined"

Comment: Since you `return` `x` and `y` in your function, you dont have to import them! just assign it to a variable like `x, y = calculate()`. Do note that (as I commented on your original answer) you should adjust your `calculate()` function to `return x, y` instead of `return x` and `return y`. The `y` is now never returned as the program never reaches it after the first `return` statement. 

Does this answer your question?

Comment: @Nobody please also see my edit to the original answer.

Comment: Thx! But where do I have to add "x, y = calculate()"? into the "parent script" within "Programm", or within "calculate.py" or "plot.py"?

Comment: @Nobody i've made another edit to clarify.

Comment: @Nobody it is not smart to use `print()` as a function name, since `print()` is also a core python function itself. You even use it inside your `print` function! to avoid weird bugs, you should rename your `print` function to something like `my_print()`.